# how to use operator overloading in c++ to display the a class (game board)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a class hexBoard and inside there is a data structure to store and display a game board

i have successfully overloaded the << operator and now in main method after creating an instance am able to display the board simply by writing cout << hex

```
 class hexBoard
 {
   vector<vector<bool>> board;
   .....
   void display();

 }
 
 ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex )
 {
     .......
     return out;
 }

 int main()
 {
   hexBoard hex;
   cout<<hex;
 }
```

this is working perfectly fine

Now my question is when am trying to display the same board from inside a member function display() by writing

#### cout<<*this

am getting errors like there is no matched type

```
 hexBoard::display()
 {
    cout<<*this;
 }
 int main()
 {
   hexBoard hex;
   hex.display();
 }
```

Please tell me where am making mistake and what is the correct way of doing this

Comment: Please, show us the compiler output. And another question: do you compile this exact code, or you fix the obvious mistakes like the forgotten "return 0;" in the main() and "void " return type for the display function ?

Comment: return 0 is completely optional for main                             and yes void display() it was a typo

Comment: @Viktor Latypov  hex.cpp: In member function ‘void hexBoard::displayBoard()’:
hex.cpp:195:11: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << *(hexBoard*)this’
hex.cpp:195:11: note: candidates are:
....... followed by some hundred lines

Comment: The type of `*this` is `hexBoard`, not `hexBoard&`...

Comment: @twalberg i dont think so, it can be either....... and thats not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found 2 solutions, one on coursera, one of the fellow student answered it

using a friend function

```
class hexBoard()
{
 friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex );

  void display()
  {
    cout<<*this;
  }
}

ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex )
{
  ......
  return out;
}

main()
{
  hexBoard hex;
  hex.display();
}
```

And this successfully works.

and 2nd one as suggested by @Stefan Näwe instead of using friend function,we can forward declare class hexBoard and then overloaded method, followed by the definition of both

```
class hexBoard;
ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex );

class hexBoard()
{
 //friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex );

  void display()
  {
    cout<<*this;
  }
}

ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out , hexBoard& hex )
{
  ......
  return out;
}

main()
{
  hexBoard hex;
  hex.display();
}
```

And I think, this one is better.

Comment: It works also if you _declare_ the `operator<<` before the class definition (and you then also need to _forward declare_ `class hexBoard`). In that case you can access only the `public` members of `hexBoard` (which is better IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not overloaded `this.operator<<(ostream&, hexBoard&)`.  Remember, `operator<<()` is overloaded outside a class because it's 1st argument can never implicitly be `this`.  So you have overloaded `operator<<(ostream&, hexBoard&)` but within your method `display()` it is looking for `this.operator<<(ostream&, hexBoard&)` which can never be.

Comment: i got it working with cout<<*this  by using a friend function
so I think it is indeed possible after all.